# How to echo <tr> using php and ajax to appear inside <table> </table>

Tags: php, html, ajax

I am currently studying ajax and php. What I want to do is to echo table rows from the php file. Here is my code.

**HTML code:**

```
<table  class = "table table-hover table-striped">
    <tr>
        <th>Product ID</th>
        <th>Product Name</th> 
        <th>Price</th> 
        <th>Terms</th>
    </tr>

<-- I want the new table row to appear here -->

</table>
```

**PHP code**

```
<?php
    $x = 10;

    while($x > 0)
    {

        echo '<tr>
                    <td>'.$x.'</td>
                    <td>'.$x.' Name</td> 
                    <td>'.$x.' Pesos</td> 
                    <td>'.$x.' Years</td>
           </tr>';

        $x--;
    }
?>
```

**Ajax script**

```
<script>
function showDetails()
{
     var xmlhttp;

     if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
         if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 &&     xmlhttp.status==200)
         {
          document.getElementById("myNewTableRow").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
         }
    }
      xmlhttp.open("POST","sample-php-ajax.php",true);
      xmlhttp.send();
    }
</script>
```

Where to put the **ID** so I can make what the php file wants to echo appear when I call it using ajax?

Comment: where is your ajax code?

Comment: I don't see any code about ajax here.

Comment: I apologize for not adding the script for ajax. I already edited it and thank you for your time reading this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the table you can use e.g. if using jQuery.

```
 $('#tableid').append($yourtr);
```

I would also put your header in a `<thead>` tag to stay on top even when you sort later.

Without jQuery you can use

```
 document.getElementById('tableid').appendChild(yourtr);
```

Comment: He is not using jQuery, isn't that clear from his Ajax code...?

Comment: The ajax code was added after I started writing the answer, however you can do the same with plain js

Comment: I apologize for that, I forgot to add the script for ajax

Comment: Change your answer to have the javascript then :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use below codes

```
<table id="result" class = "table table-hover able-striped"> // add ID here
```

in ajax get the data and append it to table by

```
document.getElementById("result").appedChild(xmlhttp.responseText)
```